# How to use the load(_:) method to load the duration of an AVAsset in iOS 16?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios16

I'm working on an iOS app that uses AVFoundation for video processing. I'm struggling to load the duration of an AVAsset asynchronously using the load(_:) method in iOS 16, as the old loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys:completionHandler:) and statusOfValue(forKey:error:) methods have been deprecated.

Here's a snippet of my current code:

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["duration"]) {
    var error: NSError?
    let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "duration", error: &error)
    // ...
}
```

I'm unsure how to replace this code to use the load(_:) method and handle errors appropriately. Could you help me update my code for iOS 16?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried replacing the loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys:completionHandler:) and statusOfValue(forKey:error:) method with the load(_:) method, as shown in the iOS 16 documentation. However, I can't figure out how to properly use it to load the duration of an AVAsset asynchronously and handle any errors.

I was expecting the new load(*:) method to allow me to load the AVAsset duration in a similar way to the old method, but I couldn't find a clear example in the documentation of how to do this. I was hoping to get help updating my code for iOS 16 using the load(*:) method.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets/retrieving_media_metadata) how Apple's documentation does it for `Title`:

```swift
let asset = AVAsset(url: {YOUR-URL-HERE})

// Load the asset's metadata.
let metadata = try await asset.load(.metadata)
// Find the title in the common key space.
let titleItems = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: metadata,
                                              filteredByIdentifier: .commonIdentifierTitle)
guard let item = titleItems.first else { return }
// Process the title item.
```

I believe you just need to replace the `.commonIdentifierTitle` with the correct identifier for `Duration`.

As for handling errors, I just put mine inside a `do/catch` block